# Can I list installed packages which were directly requested with yum?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum

I want a list of installed packages requested by the user, excluding those installed as dependencies.  This is on a CentOS 5 machine and the packages were installed using yum.  I am attempting to reconstruct what rpms were necessary to build a particularly large amount of source code.

For example, if `yum install net-snmp-devel` were run the list would not include elfutils-libelf-devel-static installed as a dependency of net-snmp-devel.

Answer (score 2):

`package-cleanup --leaves --all` will list all non-dependant packages.  This lists both packages requested directly by the user, and packages which were installed with the operating system.